# A city in Europe

Tags: geography

I'm a cheesy city, containing auk but in the main language of the country I'm in.
I have a sports team that got crowned champions of my country twice.
Also placed within me is a museum dedicated to a band that once tried to remake The Lord Of The Rings.

What city am I?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I would say it's

> Alkmaar, Netherlands

I'm a cheesy city

> One of the greatest cheese markets in the world is in Alkmaar.

Containing auk but in the main language of the country I'm in.

> Thanks to @LordofDark and @MichaSprengers: "auk but" in Dutch is "Alk Maar"

I have a sports team that got crowned twice.

> The local football team AZ Alkmaar won the national championship twice, in 1981 and 2009

Also placed within me is a museum dedicated to a band that once tried to remake The Lord Of The Rings.

> There is a museum dedicated to the Beatles, who unsucessfully tried to adapt The Lord Of The Rings.

Comment: "auk" in dutch in "alk" the first part of Alkmaar

Comment: 2 minutes faster. damn it...I mean. Good job :)

Comment: 'Auk but' = Alk Maar = Alkmaar

Comment: Haven't thought it was like this. Thanks @Lordofdark and MichaSprengers

Comment: Is it really a city though? I would have thought of it as a town.

Comment: @MrLister According to Wikipedia, it's a city. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alkmaar